# Running openssl s_client with an aes encrypted key fails

Tags: tls, openssl, key-generation

I'm trying to verify a 2-way SSL connection using the `openssl s_client` command

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:8883 -CAfile ca.pem -cert client.crt -key client.key
```

The `openssl s_client` fails with the following error:

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:8883 -CAfile ca.pem -cert client.crt -key c.key
Enter pass phrase for client.key:
unable to load client certificate private key file
140289846519624:error:0D07207B:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_get_object:header too long:asn1_lib.c:150:
140289846519624:error:0D068066:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:bad object header:tasn_dec.c:1306:
140289846519624:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:381:Type=RSA
140289846519624:error:04093004:rsa routines:OLD_RSA_PRIV_DECODE:RSA lib:rsa_ameth.c:115:
140289846519624:error:0D07207B:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_get_object:header too long:asn1_lib.c:150:
140289846519624:error:0D068066:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:bad object header:tasn_dec.c:1306:
140289846519624:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:381:Type=PKCS8_PRIV_KEY_INFO
140289846519624:error:0907B00D:PEM routines:PEM_READ_BIO_PRIVATEKEY:ASN1 lib:pem_pkey.c:132:
```

The client private key was generated using the following command

```
openssl genrsa -aes256 -out client.key 2048
```

And if I try to parse it I get the following

```
openssl asn1parse < client.key
```

I get this

```
Error in encoding
140030324189000:error:0D07207B:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_get_object:header too long:asn1_lib.c:150:
```

This does work when I generate the key without passing the `-aes256` option.

How can I get this to work with keys that have been encrypted using `aes` or `des`?

Comment: Since you encrypt your private key you must also provide the necessary information to decrypt it, see description of `-pass` option.

Comment: Do you mean the -pass (private key file pass phrase source) option ? This is for providing the passphrase of the key I suppose ? I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: "..providing the passphrase of the key I suppose" - kind of, but not directly. Please read the documentation how it should be used.

Comment: I did and used the env:var option. It picks up the passphrase ok but then throws the error. Without the option I'nm prompted for a password. Password is correct. If I provide an invalid one I get another error (failing to decrypt, indicating the passphrase is wrong).

Comment: Strange. I've tried with openssl 1.0.1e and it works for me. Maybe you should provide a test setup with cert, key and passphrase so that one could try to reproduce your problem.

Comment: So openssl genrsa -aes256 -out client.key 2048 and openssl asn1parse < client.key works fine for you ? (running it on OpenSSL 0.9.8y 5 Feb 2013 on my mac results in the header too long msg)

Comment: Because the encryption is done with the binary (ASN.1) and asn1parse itself has no way to handle encrypted data you have to decrypt it first before using asn1parse.  So it is expected that asn1parse will fail with the encrypted data. But s_client (which can handle encrypted keys) works for me.

Comment: `openssl rsa -in client.key | openssl asn1parse` will work, because it removes the encryption before calling asn1parse.